# Is it possible to use translation variable in easy admin?

Tags: symfony, translation, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm using the Easy Admin bundle to manage the back-end of my Symfony application.

I'd like to translate the following message *"max 200 characters"*

There are several properties that needs this kind of message so I'd like to make it more flexible using a variable as in Twig:

```
{{ 'max.character'|trans({'%max%': 200}) }}
```

and my message.yaml would be:

```
max:
    character: 'max %max% characters'
```

According to the [bundle documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/tutorials/i18n.html) there is nothing about variable.

So is it possible and if yes how can I use variable in this kind of way:

```
edit:
    fields:
        - {property: 'toto', label: 'toto.label', help: 'max.character' {%max%:200} }
```

Comment: Can't understand the question. Can you clarify? You want to know how to access the `max.character` setting in your Twig file to pass it to the `trans` filter? Or what? Can you add more details?

Comment: I want to use translation parameters in the yaml easy-admin config file. The documentation doesn't explain if it's possible. I just gave a regular twig example to show which kind of variable I want to add.